# MODx Revo Wayfinder 3rd level <ul> different to 2nd level <ul>?

Tags: menu, modx, templating

I've used the Wayfinder menu building extra with MODx Evo and am now attempting to use it with MODx Revo for a new site. It's working well apart from I can't yet see a way to have the 3rd level  different to the 2nd level . See the way Wayfinder is currently outputting the menu (simplified here for clarity):

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main" id="mainMenu">
<li class="dropdown"> 
     <a class="dropdown-toggle notransition" href="index.php?id=200">
        Help
        <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right " style="display: none;">
        <li>
            <a href="index.php?id=31">
                FAQs
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">
            <a href="index.php?id=54">
                Policies
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="display: none;">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php?id=490">
                        Privacy Policy
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php?id=489">
                        Terms and Conditions
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need the 'Policies' sub-menu, with 'Privacy Policy' etc, to pull to the left, not to the right - defined in Wayfinder InnerTpl:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" style="display: none;">[[+wf.wrapper]]</ul>
```

So, is it possible with Wayfinder to have a 3rd level  different to the 2nd level  ???

I've browsed the docs and forums for days to no avail and hope that the amazing SO community has some insights. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to do this with CSS, you can add the &levelClass to your wayfinder call [docs say " CSS class denoting every output row level. The level number will be added to the specified class (level1, level2, level3 etc if you specified 'level').]

that way when you can write some css for your third level items when you see something like:

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left level2">
```

your css could go something like:

```
li.dropdown-submenu.pull-left.level2 > ul {

/* css for pulling it right */

}
```

unfortunately the &levelClass does not do anything if you add [[+wf.classnames]] to the UL tag in the outer wrapper so you have to come at it sideways.

OR

your inner wrappers could be written to use a snippet to decide what classes to add:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu [[!pullLeftOrRight? &id=`[[+wf.docid]]`]]">
    [[+wf.wrapper]]
</ul>
```

Then in your snippet use the docid to determine where in the menu tree that subnav is.
[hopefully docid is available in the outerTpl - I'm not sure]

UPDATE

After reading your comments & the docs again, I think I have an idea that might work - check out the &categoryFoldersTpl attribute, setup your tpl for that with your pull right classes & for your 3rd level drop downs, set the  rel="category" on only the third level resources as suggested in the docs. [which doesn't help anyone who wants different submenus for different levels, but may get you out of your bind]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sean. I added &levelClass to the call:

`[[Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &outerTpl=`main_outerTpl` &rowTpl=`main_rowTpl` &innerTpl=`main_innerTpl` &innerRowTpl=`main_innerRowTpl` &levelClass=`level` &level=`3` &excludeDocs=`1,16,59,130`]]`

Comment: continued...

but level1, level2, level3 etc is not added by Wayfinder even though [[+wf.classnames]] is not present in any of the templates.

Any ideas?  I'm going to try your [[!pullLeftOrRight? &id=`[[+wf.docid]]`]] suggestion now...

Comment: Hmmm... it appears that docid is not available in the innerTpl. Just the string `[[+wf.docid]]` is passed to the pullLeftOrRight snippet.

Comment: Discovered Mark Hamstra's [comment](http://www.cmslesstraveled.com/index/junkdrawer/archive/2011/wayfinder-and-getresources-compare,-contrast,-combine.html) about using [[+tvname]] so changed innerTpl to:
`<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right [[+tvSubMenuClass]]" style="display: none;">[[+wf.wrapper]]</ul>`
and set tvSubMenuClass to pull-left on 'Policies' container. [[+tvSubMenuClass]] not outputted by Wayfinder.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: added an update to my answer check near the bottom of the docs for the details: http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/evo/wayfinder also - the level class should be showing on your innertpl items? you have cleared the cache & called wayfinder un-cached?

Comment: Thanks! Created the categoryFoldersTpl template and added the &categoryFoldersTpl attribute to the WF call:

`[[Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &outerTpl=`main_outerTpl` &rowTpl=`main_rowTpl` &innerTpl=`main_innerTpl` &innerRowTpl=`main_innerRowTpl` &categoryFoldersTpl=`main_categoryFoldersTpl` &level=`3`  &excludeDocs=`1,16,59,130`]]`

Set the 'Policies' container Link Attributes to rel="category" and...  Wayfinder now doesn;t output the 'Policies' dropdown :-/

Comment: continued...  Noticed in the docs that it states "The following table shows other parameters to change your output, that use the same placeholders as the &rowTpl parameter" so the &categoryFoldersTpl applies only to <li> items???

Comment: As for the level class, I've cleared the cache & tried calling wayfinder uncached and still the row elements output without level1, level2, level3 etc. Have you had success with &levelClass?

Comment: I've never had a problem with &levelClass=`lvl` just did a bit of testing and tinkering to see what we can get to show up in the wf.wrapper chunks, apparently, not much. I think you are stuck with getting the levelClass to work the going at it with some css: li.lvl2 > ul {your pull css} (going to post a wayfinder feature request)

Comment: Thanks Sean! iusemodx has [**posted**](http://forums.modx.com/thread/79137/using-wayfinder-to-add-classes-to-ul-over-multiple-levels#dis-post-476922) in the MODx forum a nice demo using CSS3 pseudo classes, including Wayfinder code and a fix for IE8. Going to see if I can adapt my current nav...